# What approaches can be used to handle 2d arrays with GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl, vulkan

My specific case being a compute shader for doing a matrix multiplication between a `n by m matrix` and a `n legnth vector` (where `n` and `m` are not known at compile time).

Comment: Use a 2D texture (image) or a Shader Storage Buffer Object

Comment: @Rabbid76 I can't quite see how this would work, mind giving an example?

Comment: I don't know what you try to achieve. What have you tried so far? See [GLSL - 4.1.9. Arrays](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#basic-types). Basically, you're looking for a tutorial. Do you want to use Vulkan or OpenGL?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Almost every compute shader reads data from one image or SSBO, processes the data, and stores it in another image or SSBO. That's the job of a compute shader. What is special about your case?

Comment: @Rabbid76 'matrix multiplication' with matricies of non constant sizes. https://hastebin.com/uxicawezul.bash I know these do not work, but they illustrate what I am trying to do.

Comment: You cannot define an 2 dimensional array, where both dimensions are open. You have to linearize the array (and to pass the dimension to the shader) or you have to use an texture image. But since n and m are not known at compile time, you don't need open arrays at all.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Ok. So how would I use these approaches for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a 2 dimensional image (see [glsl - 8.12. Image Functions](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#image-functions)):

```c
layout(r32f) uniform image2D matrixImage;

void main()
{
    // [...]

    ivec2 size = ivec2(imageSize(matrixImage));
    int n = size.x;
    int m = size.y;
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j ++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
        {
            float val = imageLoad(matrixImage, ivec2(i, j)).x;
 
            // [...]
        }
    }

    // [...]
}
```

Or write the data to a 1 dimensional open sized array in a Shader Storage Buffer Object:

```c
layout(std430) buffer TMatrix
{
  int n;
  int m;
  float data[];
} matrix;

layout(r32f) uniform image2D matrixImage;

void main()
{
    // [...]

    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.m; j ++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.n; i ++)
        {
            int index = j * matrix.n + i;  
            float val = matrix.data[index];
            
            // [...]
        }
    }

    // [...]
}
```

---

If you know the size at compile time, it is not necessary to use an open sized array ([see GLSL - 4.1.9. Arrays](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#basic-types)):

```c
const int n = 10;
const int m = 10;

layout(std430) buffer TMatrix
{
  float data[n][m];
} matrix;

void main()
{
    // [...]

    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.m; j ++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.n; i ++)
        {
            float val = matrix.data[i][j];

            // [...]
        }
    }

    // [...]
}
```